# Cut A4 design to A5 for printing

Tags: adobe-illustrator, page-layout, crop

I design a 32 pages (excluding cover and back) A5 (A4 folded to center) booklet.

While designing, I put page 1-2 in one A4 landscape format artboard, 3-4 in another, 5-6 in another, and so on.

When I sent it to print, they want me to re arrange because according to them for each printed page, page 1 should have page 32 on the other half. Page 2 should have page 31 on the other half. and so on.

I use illustrator in this booklet. Most of the artboard contains linked image that span from page1-page2.

Is there any quick way to cut and transfer half of artboard to another to rearrange the pages?

Any idea what would be the quickest way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: The problem are the images that span to both pages. I need to find a way to cut them in half. The only way I can think of now is to make 2 copies. mask one on left side and the other on right side. But this would take lots of time. I was hoping there is a smarter way to do this.

Comment: I don't know how this could be fixed, but in general InDesign works better with reshuffling pages around. Also, if your pages are A5, work in A5, otherwise you're just overcomplicating things.

Comment: There is no "quick" way to do this. The problem is that you asumed you could do your design like that and that is not the way to do it. The printer is right.

Answer (score 1):

Indesign has a "Print Booklet" feature that does exactly this.

Place the pages **in the order you'll read them** into Indesign using "facing pages".  Rearrange at will and when you're ready go to File->Print Booklet and select "saddle stitch" – that's what this kind of binding is called. You're page count has to be a multiple of 4, so you may need to add a blank page or 2 (typically an inside cover).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not the best option, given that you're going to save the artwork in pdf, create A5 artboards for individual pages (anchor the A4 page to middle-left & resize the artboard before adding a new artboard beside it).

Now that you have single-pager pdf, extract it to become a single-page pdfs (page01.pdf, page02.pdf, etc). Then either place it in InDesign for convenience (you can export them in spreads), or place the single page pdfs on A4 artboards in Illustrator.

AFAIK, a single-pager pdf is much more convenient for printers to work on rather than a spread format. Maybe because you already make the pages to look like a spread/imposed sheet, consequently they just ask you to rearrange them.